# Return dash followed by a single character

Tags: regex, grep

This works as expected:

```
([^\u0000-\u007F])+-हा([^\u0000-\u007F])+
```

Returns:

```
ब-हाणपूर
ब-हाणी
बनियन-हाफ
```

But I am looking for 1 character followed by dash. The expected output is:

```
ब-हाणपूर
ब-हाणी
```

I tried to replace + sign with character count like this...

```
([^\u0000-\u007F]){1}-हा([^\u0000-\u007F])+
```

But it returned the same 3 results. How do I return the first 2?

Comment: Use anchors `^` or word boundary `\b`. For 5 characters use `^([^\u0000-\u007F]){5}-हा([^\u0000-\u007F])+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need anchors:

```
^([^\u0000-\u007F])-हा([^\u0000-\u007F])+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7eJY94/1/)

---

You asked *'What if I need 5 characters to the left of dash?'*

The regex portion `[^\u0000-\u007F]` as written matches a **single character** that meets that criterion. If you want more or less than one, use a [regex quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) to describe how many you want.

In this case, if you want 5, you would use:

```
^([^\u0000-\u007F]{5})-हा([^\u0000-\u007F])+$
```

Comment: What if I need 5 characters to the left of dash?

Comment: Then create a regex which says five of them instead of one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Probably like this:

```
^([^\u0000-\u007F]){1}-हा([^\u0000-\u007F])+

^([^\u0000-\u007F]{1})-हा([^\u0000-\u007F]+)

(\b[^\u0000-\u007F]{1})-हा([^\u0000-\u007F]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LHLA81/1)

Comment: `{1}` is not wrong per se, but always completely useless.

Comment: @tripleee Ah, yes it's redundant for a single char, but as the OP said: ***"What if I need 5 characters to the left of dash?"***

Comment: Then`{5}` is not useless, but that's different, yes.